# How do I access a second paritition of a linux sd

Tags: linux, macos, partitioning, sd-card, raspbian

I'm having trouble finding a useful answer about this. But basically I need to edit a file manually (because I broke networking). I pulled out the sd card of my raspberry pi and injected it into my mac. The mac only picks up the boot partition but does not allow me access to any of the actually useful data.

```bash
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *63.9 GB    disk4
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 ⁨system-boot⁩             267.4 MB   disk4s1
   2:                      Linux ⁨⁩                        63.6 GB    disk4s2
```

[image: screenshot of diskutil]

```
# Disk info
Volume type : Physical Device
BSD device node : disk4
Connection : USB
Device tree path : IODeviceTree:/arm-io/usb-drd2@2280000/usb-drd2-port-ss@02200000
Writable : No
Is case-sensitive : No
Volume capacity : 63,864,569,856
Available space (Purgeable + Free) : 0
Purgeable space : 0
Free space : 0
Used space : 63,864,569,856
Owners enabled : No
Is encrypted : No
Can be verified : No
Can be repaired : No
Bootable : No
Journaled : No
Disk number : 4
Media name : Generic MassStorageClass Media
Media type : Generic
Ejectable : Yes
Solid state : No
S.M.A.R.T. status : Not Supported
```

Basically, I want to be able to access and edit `disk4s2` directly. Being able to access it via the terminal is fine, I need to change one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS does not support Linux filesystems.

You can deal with that in two ways:

1. Add a filesystem “driver”

   - via macFUSE or the like, free
   - commercial
2. Use a virtual machine (again free or commercial options exist) and pass through the drive

I recommend going with a VM running Linux because it will give you the full power of Linux. Just use Ubuntu or whatever you like. You can pass through the drive by

1. passing through the entire USB card reader device to the VM (as a USB device)
2. passing through the drive to the VM (as a drive)

You can then use `mount` and the like as you normally would on Linux.

Comment: as far as I can tell the only way to build a linux vm capable of usb passhtrough on an m1 mac is to use multipass + qemu + virt-manager but the qemu + virt-manager side of things gets complex and barely works (i haven't suceeded yet). I'm gonna try the first option..

Comment: I downloaded paragon and fixed it in 20min compared to several hours working on that vm (just because it's fun). Paragon has a free trial so if I was reading this I'd start there.

Comment: Ah, yeah. totally missed you’re on ARM. In that case, a commercial driver may be quicker or even the only feasible solution at the moment. // Don’t forget to accept this (or any) answer if it solved your question. Or do you need additional information?